# How to support Cyrillic in an iPhone/iPad app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, localization, internationalization

I have a simple program on the App Store using all standard UIKit controls, now some reviewers are complaining Cyrillic and Korean is not supported? Are the UIKit controls not using Unicode out of the box?

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Have you enabled the Cyrillic and Korean keyboards on your test device and reproduced the bug? What sort of a bug are they complaining about? Crash? Odd-looking characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Cocoa NS/CFStrings are Unicode-compliant (UCS-2 internally), Russian and Korean alphabets included. So unless your data are, at some point, passed through a single-byte-char format (a C `char[]` string, for example), all sensible languages and charsets should be supported automatically. Pay careful attention to your storage and wire formats; that's where ASCII usually lurks.

If downloading data from the Web or from an HTTP-based API, pay close attention to the charset within Content-Type header. When converting from NSData or raw memory chunks to NSString, encoding is always one of the parameters.

And, like CajunLuke said, start by reproducing the issue. If you need a "lorem ipsum"-type text, copy and paste some random nonsense from the respective Wikipedia.

I have an app in the store that deals with Russian and Japanese at the same time (it's a Japanese-Russian dictionary). No special measures were taken to ensure national charset support; however, whenever working with single-byte string, I'd keep in mind what charset is it in.

Comment: I am using a JSON REST Webservice to contact google tasks, so i think it must be the content-type header. Which one should I use to support all languages ?

Comment: You typically cannot "use" one - content-type and charset is something that the server sends you, not vice versa. You analyse the content-type that comes with the response, you extract the charset, you pick a best-fitting encoding from the list of the ones that Cocoa supports. If Google Tasks lets you choose the encoding somehow, use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested Japanese yesterday - and it worked (for predefined text strings, like Cancel and Done) in the Simulator "out of the box". Checking System Preferences > Language & Text, I see that I have many languages supported (something I did intentionally when I installed OS).

I'm assuming that you've already read Apple's [Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatSupport.html).

To see localized text, you will (for the most part) have to create it yourself and put it in Localizable.strings and .XIB files; and you will want to read up on NSLocalizedString().